# What does this error mean: com.sun.glass.ui.mac.MacApplication lambda$waitForReactivation$6 WARNING: Timeout while waiting for app reactivation?

Tags: sqlite, intellij-idea, javafx, macos-sonoma

Here are my systems details:

IntelliJ IDEA CE 2023.3 (Community Edition)
Runtime version: 17.0.9+7-b1087.7 aarch64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
macOS 14.1.2

I created a new project using JavaFX and am trying to run the default application.java file to connect my SQL Database (in the same project), but I keep getting this error:

```
com.sun.glass.ui.mac.MacApplication lambda$waitForReactivation$6
WARNING: Timeout while waiting for app reactivation
```

[image]

The error shows up after I click run and the folder named, "java" shows up in the dock of my MacBook Air, but the GUI doesn't open up and then the folder closes after like 5 seconds and the error displays in IntelliJ. I've tried to troubleshoot it as much as I can, updating my JDK to 21.0.1, updating the IntelliJ application itself, updating my laptop to Sonoma 14.1.2, but nothing has seemed to work.

Please any insight would help!

Comment: *"the GUI doesn't open up"* -> That might be because of some unrelated issue with your application (which could not be diagnosed without a [mcve]).  For me, the timeout warning only resulted in a startup delay, not a complete failure to startup.

Comment: *"connect my SQL Database (in the same project)"* -> You need to show code for how to do this and any potential errors you might receive with that (there is a reasonable chance it may be failing).  It is unrelated to the warning message mentioned in your question title (so perhaps ask a new question if you continue to receive issues after fixing the warning issue by following the instructions in the answer to this question).

Answer (score 4):

#### Bug fix for `WARNING: Timeout while waiting for app reactivation`

This timeout issue on JavaFX application startup was caused by an incompatibility with JavaFX 21 (and perhaps other earlier JavaFX versions), which was introduced when Mac OS Sonoma (OS X 14) was released.

The bug was fixed in JavaFX 21.0.1.

The solution is to use JavaFX 21.0.1+ in your application.

This issue relates to the *JavaFX version, not the JDK version*.

Reference:

- [JDK-8315657 Application window not activated in macOS 14 Sonoma](https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8315657).

---

Configuring the icon and name for the application is unrelated to the bug fix noted above.  Information on how to do that is in the answer to:

- [How can I change the app name from the default "Java" to something else with JavaFx on MacOs 14](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77721359/how-can-i-change-the-app-name-from-the-default-java-to-something-else-with-jav/77724074#77724074)

Comment: You may have exempted the unsigned application from gatekeeper scrutiny when first launching it, as suggested [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/271805/how-do-i-revoke-gatekeeper-permission-to-launch-from-an-unsigned-app).

Comment: @trashgod thanks for the info.  I didn't use `xattr` to configure the OS X security quarantine settings for applications.  I don't have full control over the security environment on my Mac as it is a managed machine.  Perhaps an admin pushed a change that allows more applications to work without signing (I don't know as I cannot view those settings with my access level). To be clear for future readers, the bug fix is unrelated to security settings for configuring the application icon and name.

Comment: I moved all info related in this answer on configuring the icon and name for a JavaFX application on OS X to the [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77721359/how-can-i-change-the-app-name-from-the-default-java-to-something-else-with-jav/77724074#77724074) and linked to that from this answer.