# How can I change the app name and icon from the default "Java" to something else with JavaFX on MacOS 14?

Tags: macos, intellij-idea, javafx, desktop-application

I want to change the app name displayed on the dock to something else instead of the default "Java".

I tried to change to use `stage.setTitle("SomeRandomTitle")` but it changes the name displayed on the window only.

I am using Intellij Idea and I am on MacOS 14.2.

App name on the dock:

[image: App name on the dock]

Answer (score 2):

#### Using `jpackage` to customize the application name and icon on OS X

The image you show is the default icon and name for a Java application running on OS X. Its display is normal.

To customize the icon displayed in the OS X dock for your application, it is necessary to create an application installer.  `jpackage` can be used to create an installer that defines a custom icon for the application.  For certain distributions, such as via the Apple app store, you may need a paid developer certificate for signing OS X applications.

The [jpackage documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/jpackage/packaging-overview.html#GUID-C1027043-587D-418D-8188-EF8F44A4C06A) describes part of the process for this:

- [Signing packages on OS X](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/jpackage/support-application-features.html#GUID-8D9F0607-91F4-4070-8823-02FCAB12238D)
- [Customizing icon resources](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/jpackage/override-jpackage-resources.html#GUID-405708DC-0243-49FC-84D9-B2A7F0A011A9)

Apple provides information on obtaining developer certificates:

- [Create Developer ID certificates](https://developer.apple.com/help/account/create-certificates/create-developer-id-certificates/)

Various types of certificates need to be obtained from Apple.  The types of certificates required differ depending on the target for the app (for instance if it will be deployable to the Apple App Store).  Information on the required types of certificates is in the linked `jpackage` documentation.

#### Example for packaging an application with a custom icon

Software used:

- OpenJDK 21.0.1
- JavaFX 21.0.1 SDK
- JavaFX 21.0.1 JMODS

All versions used were for an x64 Mac (M series processors need aarch64 JDK/SDK/JMODS for Mac and an M series Mac to create the appropriate package).

[HelloWorld.java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/get-started-tutorial/hello_world.htm) source was used.

```
package helloworld;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
 
public class HelloWorld extends Application {     
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.setText("Say 'Hello World'");
        btn.setOnAction(e ->
                System.out.println("Hello World!");                
        );
        
        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().add(btn);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

And this `module-info.java`:

```
module hello {
    requires javafx.controls;
    exports helloworld;
}
```

`JAVA_HOME` was:

```
export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 21.0.1`
```

The jar file was created using:

```
javac -p javafx-sdk-21.0.1/lib -d out module-info.java helloworld/HelloWorld.java
jar --verbose --create -p javafx-jmods-21.0.1 --file hello.jar --module-version 1.0 -C out module-info.class -C out helloworld/HelloWorld.class -C out helloworld/HelloWorld\$1.class
```

The `jpackage` command used was:

```
jpackage --icon Tatice-Cristal-Intense-Apple-multicolor.icns --name HelloApp -p javafx-jmods-21.0.1:hello.jar --module hello/helloworld.HelloWorld --type dmg
```

Where the `.icns` file was obtained from [icon archive](https://www.iconarchive.com/show/cristal-intense-icons-by-tatice/Apple-multicolor-icon.html) (annoying advertising in the link unfortunately).

You can see the result here, a custom icon image (the multi-colored apple icon) for the application and a custom name "HelloApp" as defined by the `jpackage` command, as opposed to the default folder icon and "java" name for the running application:

[image: icon image]

tree:

```
$ tree
.
├── HelloApp-1.0.dmg
├── HelloApp-1.0.pkg
├── Tatice-Cristal-Intense-Apple-multicolor.icns
├── hello.jar
├── helloworld
│   └── HelloWorld.java
├── javafx-jmods-21.0.1
│   ├── javafx.base.jmod
│   ├── javafx.controls.jmod
│   ├── javafx.fxml.jmod
│   ├── javafx.graphics.jmod
│   ├── javafx.media.jmod
│   ├── javafx.swing.jmod
│   └── javafx.web.jmod
├── javafx-sdk-21.0.1
│   ├── legal
│   │   ├── javafx.base
│   │   │   ├── ADDITIONAL_LICENSE_INFO
│   │   │   ├── ASSEMBLY_EXCEPTION
│   │   │   └── LICENSE
│   │   ├── javafx.controls
│   │   │   ├── ADDITIONAL_LICENSE_INFO
│   │   │   ├── ASSEMBLY_EXCEPTION
│   │   │   └── LICENSE
│   │   ├── javafx.fxml
│   │   │   ├── ADDITIONAL_LICENSE_INFO
│   │   │   ├── ASSEMBLY_EXCEPTION
│   │   │   └── LICENSE
│   │   ├── javafx.graphics
│   │   │   ├── ADDITIONAL_LICENSE_INFO
│   │   │   ├── ASSEMBLY_EXCEPTION
│   │   │   ├── LICENSE
│   │   │   ├── jpeg_fx.md
│   │   │   └── mesa3d.md
│   │   ├── javafx.media
│   │   │   ├── ADDITIONAL_LICENSE_INFO
│   │   │   ├── ASSEMBLY_EXCEPTION
│   │   │   ├── LICENSE
│   │   │   ├── directshow.md
│   │   │   ├── glib.md
│   │   │   ├── gstreamer.md
│   │   │   └── libffi.md
│   │   ├── javafx.swing
│   │   │   ├── ADDITIONAL_LICENSE_INFO
│   │   │   ├── ASSEMBLY_EXCEPTION
│   │   │   └── LICENSE
│   │   └── javafx.web
│   │       ├── ADDITIONAL_LICENSE_INFO
│   │       ├── ASSEMBLY_EXCEPTION
│   │       ├── LICENSE
│   │       ├── icu_web.md
│   │       ├── libxml2.md
│   │       ├── libxslt.md
│   │       └── webkit.md
│   ├── lib
│   │   ├── javafx-swt.jar
│   │   ├── javafx.base.jar
│   │   ├── javafx.controls.jar
│   │   ├── javafx.fxml.jar
│   │   ├── javafx.graphics.jar
│   │   ├── javafx.media.jar
│   │   ├── javafx.properties
│   │   ├── javafx.swing.jar
│   │   ├── javafx.web.jar
│   │   ├── libdecora_sse.dylib
│   │   ├── libfxplugins.dylib
│   │   ├── libglass.dylib
│   │   ├── libglib-lite.dylib
│   │   ├── libgstreamer-lite.dylib
│   │   ├── libjavafx_font.dylib
│   │   ├── libjavafx_iio.dylib
│   │   ├── libjfxmedia.dylib
│   │   ├── libjfxmedia_avf.dylib
│   │   ├── libjfxwebkit.dylib
│   │   ├── libprism_common.dylib
│   │   ├── libprism_es2.dylib
│   │   └── libprism_sw.dylib
│   └── src.zip
├── module-info.java
└── out
    ├── helloworld
    │   ├── HelloWorld$1.class
    │   └── HelloWorld.class
    └── module-info.class
```

#### Info regarding Apple signing certificates for recent JDK/JavaFX/OS X versions

I created am OS X package using `jpackage` with JavaFX 21.0.1 and OpenJDK 21.0.1 on OS X Sonoma 14.1.1.

Unlike my experience with earlier attempts at creating packages on OS X using `jpackage`, the resultant package (either as type `pkg` or `dmg`) was installable and usable *without signing the application with a developer certificate*.

I am not sure if this worked because of:

- Different security settings on my Mac OS OR
- Changes in recent OS X versions OR
- Changes in the JDK packaging tool for JDK 21 or some other recent JDK version OR
- some slight differences in how I created the package using `jpackage`.

Though this works, you are probably best off, for a professional installation, obtaining and using a paid certificate from Apple.  But at least, for recent software builds, it is possible to create a working installed application on OS X without using a paid certificate.

#### Notes

In related comments regarding why the unsigned application can be executed, Trashgod noted:

> You may have exempted the unsigned application from gatekeeper scrutiny when first launching it, as [suggested here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/271805/how-do-i-revoke-gatekeeper-permission-to-launch-from-an-unsigned-app).

And trashgod also provided additional information on how the application name is assigned:

> The desired bundle name should be specified in your Info.plist, [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20051727/changing-java-webstart-hover-text-over-osx-mavericks-dock-icon/20053272#20053272).

I think `jpackage` sets up the bundle name in the `Info.plist` so that the application is assigned the name configured when `jpackage` is used to build the application installer so that manual configuration of the value is not required.